# custom var_dump output for my class

Tags: php, var-dump

is it possible to override var_dump output for a custom class?
I want something like this:

```
class MyClass{
    public $foo;
    public $bar;
    //pseudo-code
    public function __dump($foo, $bar)
    {
        return 'Foo:$foo, bar:$bar';
    }
}

var_dump(array($instanceOfMyClass));
//it should output this:
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  class MyClass#1 (2) {
    Foo:valueOfFoo, bar:valueOfBar
  }
}
```

I know I can use some 3rd-party var_dump alternatives, but I want to customize behavior for var_dump in my library project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

In **PHP 5.6.0+**, you can use the [`__debugInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo) magic function to customize the output of [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

> `array __debugInfo ( void )`
>
> This method is called by [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) when dumping an object to get the properties that should be shown. If the method isn't defined on an object, then all public, protected and private properties will be shown.
>
> This feature was added in PHP 5.6.0.

#### Example:

```
class MyDateTime{
    public $year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second;
    public function __debugInfo() {
        return array(
            'date' => $this->year . "-" . $this->month . "-" . $this->day,
            'time' => sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $this->hour, $this->minute, $this->second),
        );
    }
}

$dt = new MyDateTime();
$dt->year = 2014; $dt->month = 9; $dt->day = 20;
$dt->hour = 16; $dt->minute = 2; $dt->second = 41;
var_dump($dt);
```

#### Output by PHP 5.6.0:

```
object(MyDateTime)#1 (2) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(9) "2014-9-20"
  ["time"]=>
  string(8) "16:02:41"
}
```

#### Output by PHP 5.0.0 - 5.5.16:

```
object(MyDateTime)#1 (6) {
  ["year"]=>
  int(2014)
  ["month"]=>
  int(9)
  ["day"]=>
  int(20)
  ["hour"]=>
  int(16)
  ["minute"]=>
  int(2)
  ["second"]=>
  int(41)
}
```

#### Notes:

1. [`__debugInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo) must return an `array`. I got an error on PHP 5.6.0 for returning a `string`:

> Fatal error: __debuginfo() must return an array in /somepath/somefile.php on line 15
>
> It seems to work with [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) too, although this doesn't seem documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

For this you could use the ReflectionClass functions and build your own function to get the informations you need.

http://php.net/manual/de/reflectionclass.tostring.php
http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't affect output of var_dump. Is var_dump output hardwired, or can it be customized for a particular class?

Comment: You can't override php functions. You can build your own var_dump function and grab all the information you need.

Comment: I don't want to override PHP function, I want to customize its behavior for a particular class. The question was if the behavior of var_dump for a particular class can be overriden i.e. by magic method.

Answer (score 0):

You cant overwrite core PHP functions.

You could add the function __toString() in your object:

```
class myClass {
    public function __toString(){
        // custom var_dump() content here then output it
    }
}

$myClass = new myClass();

echo $myClass;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to use __toString. I want to simplify the var_dump output when dumping complex structures of generic PHP classes, and some of my classes between them which can be dumped a more simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make sense override var_dump result, you can just use toString() magic method

```
class MyClass{
public $foo;
public $bar;
public function test(){}
public function __toString()
 {
    $vars="Variables:";
    foreach(get_class_vars(__CLASS__) as $name => $value) $vars.="<br> $name : {$this->{$name}}".gettype($this->{$name});
    return __CLASS__.':<br>'.$vars.'<br>Methods:<br>'.implode('<br>',get_class_methods(__CLASS__));
 }
}

$lol = new MyClass();
$lol->foo = 10;
$lol->bar = 'asd';

 echo $lol;
```

Example [HERE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/q30bH8)

Comment: know how to use toString. The point is, I have complex object structure (PHP arrays and other classes), part of the structure are my class objects that can be simplified. I want to dump whole this structure with var_dump, with customized output of the part of my class.

Comment: you can't costumize the output because var_dump is a php function with direct output, the most you can do is filter the output with ob_ functions and edit that with some regular expressions but it's not recommended

Answer (score 0):

If You're looking for a more readable (subjectively) var_dump, I've written something like that some time ago, maybe it'll be of use to You :)

I wanted to print_r every object as if it was an array. The quality of the code is not the best, but it helped me when I couldn't use XDebug.

```php
class XDump
{
    private static array $object_hash = []; //workaround for cyclic dependencies

    public static function dump($var, bool $withContent = true, ?int $maxDepth = null): void
    {
        $dumpVar = self::convertToArray($var, $withContent, $maxDepth);
        print_r($dumpVar);
        exit();
    }

    private static function convertToArray($var, bool $withContent, ?int $maxDepth)
    {
        self::$object_hash = [];

        if (!$withContent) {
            return self::getArrayStructure($var, $maxDepth);
        }

        return self::getArray($var, $maxDepth);
    }

    private static function getArray($obj, ?int $maxDepth, $mainKey = '', int $depth = 0)
    {
        $simpleReturn = self::getSimpleReturn($obj, $mainKey);
        if (null !== $simpleReturn) {
            return $simpleReturn;
        }

        $result = [];
        $objectArray = (array)$obj;
        foreach ($objectArray as $key => $item) {
            if (!$maxDepth || $depth <= $maxDepth) {
                $result[$key] = self::getArray($item, $maxDepth, $key, $depth + 1);
            }
        }

        return self::shortenArray($result);
    }

    private static function getArrayStructure($obj, ?int $maxDepth, $mainKey = '', int $depth = 0)
    {
        $simpleReturn = self::getSimpleReturn($obj, $mainKey);
        if (null !== $simpleReturn) {
            return $simpleReturn;
        }

        $result = [];
        $objectArray = (array)$obj;
        foreach ($objectArray as $key => $item) {
            if (self::hasChildren($item)) {
                if (!$maxDepth || $depth <= $maxDepth) {
                    $result[$key] = self::getArrayStructure($item, $maxDepth, (string)$key, $depth + 1);
                }
            } else {
                self::throwErrorIfNotPrintable($key, $mainKey);
                $result['elements'][] = $key;
            }
        }
        if (isset($result['elements'])) {
            $elements = implode(' | ', $result['elements']);
            if (1 === \count($result)) {
                return $elements;
            }

            $result['elements'] = $elements;
        }

        return self::shortenArray($result);
    }

    private static function hasChildren($obj): bool
    {
        return \is_object($obj) || \is_array($obj);
    }

    private static function getHashIfAlreadyHashed($obj): ?string
    {
        $hash = self::getObjectHash($obj);
        $existingHash = self::$object_hash[$hash] ?? null;
        self::$object_hash[$hash] = $hash;

        return $existingHash;
    }

    private static function throwErrorIfNotPrintable($obj, string $name = 'object'): void
    {
        if (!self::isPrintable($obj)) {
            $type = \gettype($obj);
            throw new ServerException("Value of {$name} with type {$type} is not handled!");
        }
    }

    private static function isPrintable($obj): bool
    {
        return is_scalar($obj) || null === $obj;
    }

    private static function getSimpleReturn($obj, $mainKey)
    {
        if (\is_object($obj)) {
            if (is_subclass_of($obj, \DateTimeInterface::class)) {
                return TimeHelper::toDateTimeString($obj);
            }
            if (\Closure::class === \get_class($obj)) {
                return 'Closure';
            }

            $existingHash = self::getHashIfAlreadyHashed($obj);
            if (null !== $existingHash) {
                return "Already hashed somewhere else as {$existingHash}!";
            }
        }

        if (\is_string($obj)) {
            $jsonData = json_decode($obj, true);
            if ($jsonData) {
                $jsonData['XDump_IS_JSON_STRING'] = true;

                return $jsonData;
            }
        }

        if (\is_resource($obj)) {
            $type = get_resource_type($obj);

            return "PHP resource with type: {$type} in {$mainKey}";
        }

        if (!self::hasChildren($obj)) {
            self::throwErrorIfNotPrintable($obj);

            return $obj;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static function shortenArray(array $retArray): array
    {
        $shortenRet = [];
        foreach ($retArray as $key => $item) {
            $shortKey = self::shortenKey((string)$key);
            $shortenRet[$shortKey] = $item;
        }

        return $shortenRet;
    }

    private static function shortenKey($key): string
    {
        try {
            $parts = explode("\0", $key);
            $shortKey = end($parts);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $shortKey = $key;
        }

        return $shortKey;
    }

    private static function getObjectHash($obj): string
    {
        return \get_class($obj).'|'.spl_object_hash($obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have a var_dump output, I just paste it in https://www.spaggetticode.com/text-manipulation/php-dump so that I can view it as JSON or PHP array code instead. Maybe useful?

For example, my `var_dump` output was

```
array(1) {
  ["object"]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (4) {
    ["create"]=>
    string(6) "sipper"
    ["faom"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["roam"]=>
      object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
        ["coam"]=>
        string(4) "zoam"
        ["bob"]=>
        string(3) "rob"
        ["fas"]=>
        int(124)
      }
      ["fas"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
    ["zom"]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
      ["hello"]=>
      string(5) "world"
    }
    ["vom"]=>
    object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2023-08-29 14:52:23.647869"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(3) "UTC"
    }
  }
}
```

and the tool converts it to

```php
return [
  "object" => (object)[
    "create" => "sipper",
    "faom" => [
      "roam" => (object)[
        "coam" => "zoam",
        "bob" => "rob",
        "fas" => 124,
      ],
      "fas" => false,
    ],
    "zom" => (object)[
      "hello" => "world",
    ],
    "vom" => new DateTime([
      "date" => "2023-08-29 14:52:23.647869",
      "timezone_type" => 3,
      "timezone" => "UTC",
    ]),
  ],
];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your contribution, however the OP asked for a solution that will "*customize behavior for var_dump in my library project*" rather than use an external website on the output everytime to reformat it. If this answer can be adapted to answer the specific question asked, then you can [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77001550/edit) to add the relevant information.